# Issue copying data to cosmosdb via Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to move data from a Blob Storage to a cosmos instance, because I use Azure Data Factory. I've created an instance of Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB (4.0 server version) and I've configured an Azure Private Link for it. Since I have a private link, I am trying to connect to the cosmos via self-hosted integration runtime.

The endpoint is  `mongo.cosmos.azure.com` which is not supported by ADF so I've changed the endpoint to `.documents.azure.com`, but I'm getting a `Connection to MongoDB server is timeout` error.

Connection string:

```
mongodb://Mycosmos-01:Key1@Mycosmos.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true
```

Exception:

```
Connection to MongoDB server is timeout.
A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using 
CompositeServerSelector { 
  Selectors = ReadPreferenceServerSelector { 
    ReadPreference = { Mode : Primary } 
  }, 
  LatencyLimitingServerSelector { AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } 
}. 
Client view of cluster state is { 
  ClusterId : "2", 
  ConnectionMode : "Automatic", 
  Type : "Unknown", 
  State : "Disconnected", 
  Servers : [{ 
    ServerId: "{ 
      ClusterId : 2, 
      EndPoint : "Unspecified/Mycosmos.documents.azure.com:10255"
    }"
```

Is there any idea how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your output connector configuration (obviously with obscured "real" credentials or endpoint names). Also, can you please confirm that you're using the Cosmos DB MongoDB API connector, and not the SQL API connector?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I've updated the question with the connection string. Yes, I use a Link Service for Azure CosmosDB Mongo API Connector.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string pattern for [CosmosDbMongoDbApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db-mongodb-api#linked-service-properties) is

```
mongodb://<cosmosdb-name>:<password>@<cosmosdb-name>.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb
```

In your connection string cosmos DB name is not the same at both places.

Replace your connection string with **`mongodb://Mycosmos-01:Key1@ Mycosmos-01.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true`**